# Strings and Integers Android Studio

Tags: java

I basically want to put an int inside of a string, when I do so I get the following error:

`QuestionModel(String,java.lang.String) in QuestionModel cannot be applied to (String,int)`

This is the Code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n1 = rand.nextInt(11);
int y1 = rand.nextInt(12);

int answer1 = n1+y1;

public void setUpQuestion(){

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel(n1 +"+"+ y1 + " = ?", n1+y1));
```

Basically, I want the answer to this question to be the product of `n1` and `y1`, I'm using a string in a different file and yes, the code above does work in my math quiz which I have, but instead of having `n1+y1` for the answer I can put any number in there and that will be the answer I'd have to input into my quiz in order to get it correct and also the n1+y1 generates two random numbers between 0-12 and 0-11. This is my QuestionModel file :

```
package com.garnett.mathspeeder;

import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionModel {
    public QuestionModel(String questionString, String answer) {
        QuestionString = questionString;
        Answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestionString() {
        return QuestionString;
    }

    public void setQuestionString(String questionString) {
        QuestionString = questionString;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        Answer = answer;
    }

    private String QuestionString;
    private String Answer;

}
```

Anyone got any idea's how to solve this? I've been trying different methods for a few days now and none of them work out.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: What do you want exactly? Please explain.

Comment: `String.valueOf(n1+y1)`

Comment: `Integer.toString(n1+y1);`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, really appreciate your help!

Comment: `QuestionModel (String, java.lang.String) in QuestionModel cannot be applied to (String, int)` just means that the method *requires*  a `String` but is being called with an `int` - so the question is just "how to convert an `int` into a `String`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an int to a string use `String.valueOf(your_int);`

So, your code becomes:

`questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel(n1 + "+" + y1 + " = ?", String.valueOf(n1 + y1)));`

Also, instead of writing `n1 + "+" + y2`, you should write `String.format("%d + %d", n1, y2);`

Comment: I've downvoted when saw you've added a answer which is added already. But, now put off it and voted up as you've explained and detailed it.   But, you're not allowed to use hatespeech here.

Comment: @AAShakil but your answer uses Integer.toString, it's Lino who anticipated me, not you, and I didn't see his answer when I clicked "Post"

Comment: @AAShakil I posted my answer before you commented. And you shouldn't downvote correct answers and discourage people like that.

Answer (score -2):

You could convert the int into a Sting Try `String.valueOf(n1+y1)`

Comment: I got two downvotes for a correct answer!? I should not answer questions here any more.

Comment: some downvoters can be ridiculous, I agree, but your answer isn't properly formulated, you say "convert the int into an". An what?

Comment: Oh yes. didn't see that.